# How to group orders by different cities using Laravel, MySql, JSON

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5, e-commerce

Trying to build a report result of orders related information of a laravel project. But struggling to find out a solution on a specific data structure.

My Request :

```
// Date Ranges
$fromDate = $this->request->fromDate;
$toDate = $this->request->toDate;
```

So the result should be within a date range.

My orders table :

```
order_id    order_addresses    grand_total
------------------------------------------
  1           JSON DATA          3,000.00
  2           JSON DATA          2,000.00
  3           JSON DATA          1,500.00
```

So My `JSON DATA` looks like this :

```
{
   "delivery_address":{
      "House":"Offline House",
      "Street":"Offline Road",
      "Area":"Offline Area",
      "PostCode":"1230",
      "City":"City1",
      "Country":"Country1",
      "ContactPerson":"Offline User",
      "ContactNumber":"01XXXXXXXX"
   }
}
```

I just want the response as :

```
    {
        "orders": 3, // How many orders are there in that particular city
        "totals": "5,500.00", // Total how much the cost of orders in that city
        "groupby": "City1",
    },
    {
        "orders": 5,
        "totals": "7,500.00", 
        "groupby": "City2",
    },
    ...,
    ...
```

*I am seeking a solution using query builder in laravel with MySQL.*

**This is an existing project so I can't really change the structure how it was built. So, any suggestions on how I can extract the cities from JSON DATA having relation with the orders identity along with the totals and all.
I just need the order_ids I think city wise then I can structure my result anyway I like to achieve end result.**

*If anything confusion here, please let me know so that I can make it clear.*

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest grouping fetched data using Laravel Collection functions.

**Order Model**

```php
class Order extends Model {

    // This will cast data to native types.
    // so order_address json string to array
    protected $casts = [
        'order_addresses' => 'array',
    ];

}
```

**Controller function**

```php
// Fetch orders from the database as you usually do
// without considering about grouping.
// with your conditions.
// I will simply use all() for example.
$orders = Order::all();

// First group by city
// Then map to get the result you want.
$groupedOrders = $orders->groupBy(function($order) {

    // since we added it to the casts array in the model
    // laravel will automatically cast json string to an array.
    // So now order_address is an array.
    return $order->order_addresses['City'];
})
->map(function($groupedOrders, $groupName) {
    return [
        'orders' => $groupedOrders->count(),
        'totals' => $groupedOrders->sum('grand_total'),
        'groupby' => $groupName,
    ];
});
```